# Issue while creating the Channel URI for push notifications in Windows

Tags: c++, push-notification, uri, windows-app-sdk, wns

I am trying out the Windows Notification Service (WNS) to have push notifications for my Windows application. But I am facing an issue while creating the token. What is wrong here? (Trying to use C++ WinRT APIs).

In application where I am using Windows AppSDK:

This is the below function where I am requesting the Channel URI.

```
winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<PushNotificationChannel> RequestChannelAsync()
{
    // remote Id is the Azure AppId
    auto channelOperation{ PushNotificationManager::Default().CreateChannelAsync(remoteId) };

    // Setup the in-progress event handler
    channelOperation.Progress(
        [](auto&& sender, auto&& args)
        {
            if (args.status == PushNotificationChannelStatus::InProgress)
            {
                // This is basically a noop since it isn't really an error state
                std::cout << "\nWNS Channel URI request is in progress." << std::endl;
            }
            else if (args.status == PushNotificationChannelStatus::InProgressRetry)
            {
               
            }
        });

    auto result{ co_await channelOperation };

    if (result.Status() == PushNotificationChannelStatus::CompletedSuccess)
    {
        auto channel{ result.Channel() };

        std::cout << "\nWNS Channel URI: " << winrt::to_string(channel.Uri().ToString()) << std::endl;

        // It's the caller's responsibility to keep the channel alive
        co_return channel;
    }
    else if (result.Status() == PushNotificationChannelStatus::CompletedFailure)
    {
        co_return nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        co_return nullptr;
    }

}
```

Reference: https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK-Samples/blob/main/Samples/Notifications/Push/cpp-console-unpackaged/cpp-console-unpackaged.cpp

The channelStatus remains in Started. It doesn't print the line 'In Progress' and comes out of the loop.  Why this is happening?

### Edit

The channel URI gets request in Progress. But, after even waiting for more than 10 minutes, I am not able to reach at any of the else if condition where I am checking the result.

But it goes inside this condition of below if. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
winrt::Microsoft::Windows::PushNotifications::PushNotificationChannel
RequestChannel()
{
    auto task{ RequestChannelAsync() };
    if (task.wait_for(std::chrono::minutes(10)) != AsyncStatus::Completed)
    {

            IAsyncInfo  infor         = task.as<IAsyncInfo> ();

            uint32_t    id            = infor.Id ();
            HRESULT     errorCode     = infor.ErrorCode ();
            AsyncStatus currentStatus = infor.Status ();

        task.Cancel();
        return nullptr;
    }

    auto result{ task.GetResults() };
    return result;
}
```

Comment: There is the [remark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.windows.pushnotifications.pushnotificationmanager.createchannelasync?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4#remarks) in the document "In most cases channel creation requests should complete in a few seconds. Because this is a network operation, channel request operations can fail initially, which triggers retry logic built-in to the platform. **In these cases channel request operations can take between 2 and 16 minutes.**" Have you tried waiting ten minutes or more?

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT I have tried waiting for more than ten minutes, but still it fails. I tried using the AsyncInfo and the status remains in 'Started' state. Can you please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Does this compulsory should happen on main thread? Fetching/Creating the channel URI

Comment: Can [both examples](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK-Samples/tree/046667c598540e887a303bd271a7524671363d65/Samples/Notifications/App) reproduce the same behavior?

Comment: I haven't tried that but I have shared my project where this fails. @JunjieZhu-MSFT
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1531372/how-to-generate-the-channel-uri-for-winui3-applica